# How to Test if 1 Factor Influences Another

Tags: time-series, correlation, forecasting

How do I test to see if the red data influences the blue data? In otherwords, how does the blue data respond to changes in the red data From an eyeball test it looks like it kind of sort of does. How do I quantify this?

[image]

Comment: Could you tell us what this variables really IS?

Comment: does it matter? but in read is the count of mentions of a certain keyword in an aggregate of articles, and in the blue is the standardized trading volume of a certain futures contract for that day

Comment: So you ask if one variable is leading the other? Can you show us the crosscorrelation function?

Comment: Are you still interested in this question? If yes, please show us some plots (scatterplot, acf, ccf)? If noy, you can delete it yourself.